# How does Google Plus cache login information on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I done with login any getting user profile with google plus.

When I Logout from my app without calling GoolePlus signOut with in App

```
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]signOut];
```

Now user goes to GooglePlus App and explicitly logOut from app or clear all safari history and cookies
And user login in with another account in GooglePlus.

Now when I again logIn in myApp with GoolePlus I am getting previous account information not new one. Here is my code-

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = ttGooglePlusClientID;
[GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];

GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.clientID = ttGooglePlusClientID;
signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, @"profile" ];
signIn.delegate = self;

[signIn authenticate];
```

To avoid these I used these code before calling to logIn with `GooglePlus`

```
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]hasAuthInKeychain]) {

    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]signOut];
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]disconnect];
}
```

but in this case each time it is redirecting to GoolePlus app or safari.

How to avoid this?

Comment: That is odd. signOut definitely clears the keychain. The user shouldn't need to sign out of Google+ or Safari as both have account choosers built in. Are you using the latest version of the Google+ iOS SDK (1.5.0)? If not, could you try that version and see if it works any better?

Comment: Ya I tried with latest vesrion 1.5.0 But still same problem. I logOut from app withouy calling `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]signOut];` So when I again login with google plus even I changed account in `googlePlus` app it give me last login user profile only. If I call `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]signOut];` while logOut from app anf again try to login it takes me googlePlus app to select account.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour of signOut - you do have to reconsent each time as it clears the keychain refresh token, so you have to see a new consent screen when signing back in (even if you have previously granted access).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this ? Or any way to clear keychain and use `trySilentAuthentication`. This is look like somewhat odd.

Comment: Clear keychain and trysilent will always fail, as trysilent checks the keychain. Could you update your question with a step by step if the user experience you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ian Barber, as a new user of the 1.5.1 SDK and digging through all the SO posts I can find, I must admit that the intended usage of the SDK is somewhat opaque.  Google would be well-served if you or someone at Google would provide a robust sample app demonstrating example authentication flow demonstrating in a single app: A) Initial authentication, B) "Silent" authentication, C) Logout, and D) Revoking.  The code snippets on the developer page while informative in isolation do not demonstrate a fully working sample. Just my thoughts.  Given the issues we've had, we'll likely punt on GP.

Comment: @IanBarber It seems signOut does indeed clear the keychain.  For trysilent, does it really return YES if the user revoked access (as indicated in the headers)?  It might be useful to have a query method so that apps could query if access was revoked and if desired perform the non-silent authentication.

Comment: It will return yes but the finished with auth callback will have the error value set. Re sample, maybe look at Photohunt for a worked example.

Comment: @IanBarber Is the specific error value/string that indicates revoked access documented somewhere?  On Photohunt page it says: "The Google+ iOS SDK automatically handles retrieving new access tokens as needed, but if the token is to be used externally it is important to use the authorizeRequest:completionHandler method in the GTMOAuth2Authentication object."  1) The SDK does not handle retrieving a new token automatically (in current form user of SDK must call signOut/signIn)  2) The requirement to use authorizeRequest if token is to be used externally is not documented on the SDK signin page.

Comment: Re sample, simple sample referenced from the iOS SDK signin page (not SO comments) will help developers and adoption.  Please consider this as feedback (not criticism) and please consider the value of one-to-many support you can provide by putting this in an easy to find place.

Comment: There isn't a specific error to do with revoked (it just looks like the refresh failed), but it doesn't overly matter - if you get an error there when the trySilentAuth said yes its prompt for a refreshed auth. Thanks for the suggestion re referencing Photohunt in more places.